# ActionScript 3 code learning

Tags: actionscript-3, programming-languages, var

What does this statement (i = 0; i++); mean in ActionScript 3 or in computer programming in general?

Comment: Seems like i got promoted to 1 ?

Comment: it means you should use google more often

Comment: i++ is the same as writing i=i+1 or i+=1

Comment: Why is this downvoted and votes to close? Even-though this is a very basic question it is still la legit question

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean `i=0;i<number;i++`?

It's usually written as a `for` loop. It means you want to loop some action specific number of times.

the first part declares a variable, the second shows how many times to loop and the last one shows by how much you want to increment. i++ means you want i to increment by 1

for example

```
for( i=0; i<10; i++){
      do_action();
}
```

it will loop 10 times and execute your code in the bracets